# Query processing time is more..performance issue in retrieving data

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-performance

I have bit complicated model design with many associations among themselves. 
Here is model design

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :records

validates :email, presence: true

end
```

Record Model

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user

 has_many :record_type_student
 has_many :record_type_employee
 has_many :record_type_other

end
```

RecordTypeStudent Model

```
  class RecordTypeStudent < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :record
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :source

end
```

Similar Model for other two RecordTypeOther and RecordTypeEmployee

I have Added index as well in RecordTypeStudent, Other and Employee from Record for fast retrieval. 
Currently retreiving 1000 records including all three takes 2.4 seconds which I think is alot. 
Here is how I am querying my records 
first Query

```
@records = Record.where(:user_id => 1)
@r = []
@records.each do |m|
  if !r.record_type_students.empty?
    @r += r.record_type_students
  end
  if !r.record_type_other.empty?
    @r += r.record_type_others
  end
  if !r.record_type_employees.empty?
    @r += r.record_type_employees
  end
end
```

The processing time is very low and it is only 1000 records so I am not sure is bad queries that I am doing or something else.

Application is using MySQl for data base

```
Completed 200 OK in 2338ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 445.5ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like you are creating a lot of unnecessary queries. Instead of pulling out the records and iterating over them (which should have been done with `.find_each` rather than `.each`), you can query the individual record types with the right records which will result in an `IN` clause and will be done on the database side. If I am understanding your schema correctly, you can get the same data as follows (AR 4.1.1):

```
record = Record.where(user_id: 1)
r = []
r += RecordTypeStudent.where(record: record).to_a
r += RecordTypeEmployee.where(record: record).to_a
r += RecordTypeOther.where(record: record).to_a
```

This will result in 3 queries total. You can make the code cleaner as follows:

```
r = [RecordTypeStudent, RecordTypeEmployee, RecordTypeOther].flat_map do |type|
  type.where(record: Record.where(user_id: 1)).to_a
end
```

If you want to further drop the number of queries, you could get the data via `UNION` between those tables but I don't think that's necessary.

*I guess it's just here in the question's text but those `has_many` in the `Record` model have to be specified with plural arguments, otherwise it won't work.*

Comment: Thanks for answer, sorry I forgot to put plural in record model, but this is not working as it is complaining  Unknown column 'record_type_students.records' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

Comment: What version of Rails (and consequently AR) are you using? If you're using some older version, it might not recognize the association. Try `.where(record_id: Record.where(user_id: 1))` instead.

Comment: I am using rails 4.0.2 and consequent AR

Comment: Yeah, that is too old to recognize the association. Just try using `record_id` instead of `record` in the where statement.

Comment: Thanks for inputs I have solved the problem, but I have a question do you know some library to build json fast I am using Jbuilder with multijson and it is taking 6 second for 10000 records ...

Comment: Well, you might need to experiment with all of the supported backends to see how they perform for your use case (multijson automatically tries to use the best backend available). The fastest seems to be https://github.com/ohler55/oj , just add it to your Gemfile.

Comment: Thanks for this, I would give it a try